# Accessing variable declared in aspx.cs in aspx or variable declared in ascx.cs ascx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I was asked a question in an interview, weather we can access a publically declared variable which is been declared in aspx.cs or ascx.cs page in aspx or ascx page respectively.

Comment: check following link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406961/how-to-call-a-variable-in-code-behind-to-aspx-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, As far as it's **Publicly** declared at ***Page Level***, you can access it .
for writing
    `<%= Variable %>`
for computation and 
     `<% variable %>`
for binding
    `<%# variable %>`

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, In ASPX page you can do:

```
<%=yourVariable%>
```

If you have defined in your code behind file `.cs` file as:

```
public string yourVariable;
```

If you want to use it in a span in aspx page then:

```
<span> <%= yourVariable %> </span>
```

You may see: [Accessing CodeBehind Variables or C# Variables, Methods in ASPX Page in ASP.Net](http://codes.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/17-Accessing-Codebehind-Variable-and-methods-in-ASPX-page.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

in similar case, anyone helps

in `aspx` file:

```
 <%= SessionLengthMinutes %> minute(s), <%=Session["name"] %>
```

in aspx.cs :

```
public int SessionLengthMinutes
{
   get { return Session.Timeout; }
}
```

i have declared it as public, even though it was unable to access the `aspx.cs` elements in `aspx` file.

thanks