# Convert string to int then multiply another int

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, int

I am working with someone else's code and I'm not good with C# at all!

I need to multiply `total1` and `total2`. The code below gives me `answer = 0` and that's not right. What is wrong here?! Also, the value of `total1` is saved in a MS SQL database as an int if that matters. When I put in a breakpoint on the last line I notice it's reading `total2` as `9` and `total1` as `"15"` (with the quotes).

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection pcn;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand pcm;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader prs;
pcn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("");
pcm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
pcn.Open();
pcm.Connection = pcn;
var tableSql = String.Format(@"select sum(TicSold) as total1 from BusTickets where TicketType = '9'");
pcm.CommandText = tableSql;
prs = pcm.ExecuteReader();
var rowcount = 0;
while (prs.Read())
{
    rowcount++;
    total1 = prs["total1"].ToString();
}
prs.Close();
pcn.Close();

int total2 = 9;
int answer = total2 * Convert.ToInt32(total1);
```

**UPDATE:** I was able to get answer to show the correct number rather than 0 by using Justin's method below, but now I want to show "answer" on the .aspx page. Previously, I would make it public (public int answer) and then in my html put <%= answer %> for the amount to show. But it still shows 0. The code above is my code behind, the code below is my main page. Again, sorry for the lack of knowledge on this, I'm learning.

```
Total Ticket Profit: <strong><%= answer %></strong></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you get the info from the database as an int, as opposed to converting it to string then back again? Does `total1 = prs["total1"]` by itself work?

Comment: Have you debug your code? what value are you getting in total1 variable

Comment: can you check its value on debug?? Then I would also suggest to use `Int32.TryParse` Method instead than using `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @Sachin When I debug I get "15" for total1, thats with quotes around the 15.

Comment: @devilfish17 your right, I should leave it as an Int, my bad!

Comment: On your second try you can only get 1) an exception for the `int.Parse` 2) a result for total3.  How could you get 0 unless total3 or total2 is 0?  You said total2 was 9, so if total3 is 15 you can only get 135.

Comment: @Harrison Look neither are 0! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9446763/code/int2.jpg

Comment: So after the next line executes answer will be 135, right?  What is answer after that line executes?

Comment: Yes, it becomes 135, you are right. But when I call it to the front page <%= answer %> it still shows as 0. I have it as public int answer; on code behind

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: @Harrison I updated it, let me know if that helps. I just want to take the answer int from the code behind to the front page now within my HTML.

Comment: see updated **answer** below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `Convert.ToInt32` help page you have the return value shows:

```
Type: System.Int32
A 32-bit signed integer that is equivalent to the number in value, or 0 (zero) if value is null.
```

Therefore the "15" that is value for total1 must be returning 0 from the `Convert` method giving you a total of zero (0) after the multiplication.

I would recommend using

```
int answer = 0;
int myTotal = 0;

if(int.TryParse(total1, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,out myTotal))
{
     answer = myTotal * total2;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your updated question looks like it can be answered by looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406983/2145211).  It defines the variable as a public property and then calls it similary to how you did `<%=answer%>`

```
public string Answer { get { return answer.ToString(); } }
```

or returning the result of the method you are showing which calculates answer (assuming its return value is answer).

Comment: When I use your code I get an error "namespace system.globalization no overload for method parse takes 4 arguments"

Comment: my mistake.  That was supposed to be TryParse.  I'll fix it

Answer (score 3):

The value should already be an integer coming out of the database so, when reading the value, you should only have to cast the value:

```
int total1 = (int)prs["total1"];
```

Comment: I still get answer = 0 when doing this. The only thing that did change is now during debug the total1 = 15 and not "15".

Comment: I had my breakpoint at the wrong spot, you were right this fixed the equation. Still working on it displaying the number on my front page though.

Answer (score 1):

total1 ISNULL ?

```
int iTotal1 = answer  = 0;
if(int.TryParse(total1,out iTotal1 ))
{
     answer = total2 * Convert.ToInt32(total1);
}else{
    // total1 Not Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have already asked in the comments to your original question, I'd recommend looking into the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method instead, as you don't really need to loop through a recordset when only one result is being returned.

But, to answer your question, where is `total2` coming from?  The variable `total1` by itself is certainly going to return a string, since when you set it you are casting the DB result to string. (Where is this variable being declared? e.g., `string total1`?) Try instead delcaring as `int total1` and then when getting the result, `total1 = Convert.ToInt32(prs["total1"]);`. I hope this helps and good luck to you!

Comment: total2 is always going to be 9. It's just the amount the tickets cost, what I'm trying to do is find how many tickets are in the database then multiply the total sum of tickets by 9.

Comment: Are there are any nulls in the TicSold column? Convert.ToInt32 will change this to zero?

Comment: There are no nulls in the column there is only two records right now, one with the value of 2 and one with the value of 4.

Comment: Please try declaring `total1` as an int, and lose all the string/ToString cruft, then see if you get a more meaningful error?

Comment: No luck, still getting 0. hmm https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9446763/code/int.jpg

Comment: Great picture! But try hovering over both total1 and total2---which of them is the zero?

Comment: Neither! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9446763/code/int2.jpg I'm so confused now!

Comment: @kcray You're breaking before the result has been assigned to the `answer` variable. Either break on the curly brace, then hover over `answer`, or try hovering over the `*` sign on your current breakpoint.

Comment: @keyboardP Your right, ah man I'm a noob, okay so I moved the break and now answer = 135 like it should. But when I call it on the actual page like <%= answer %> it shows up as 0. Any idea on that? Within the public partial class I state it as public int answer;