# Pass int from aspx.cs to aspx page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I need to pass an int from aspx.cs page to aspx page and show it there

relevant part of example.aspx.cs page:

```
public partial class example : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected int Id(){
            var Id = 318;
            return Id;
            }
    }
```

Relevant part of aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="example.aspx.cs" Inherits="blahblah.example" %>
.
.
.
<body>
    <h1>example.Id()</h1>
.
.
.
```

How can I edit this? It should be straight foward, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: can you not use `QueryString` here..? or better yet for example you could do something like this 
`<h1><%=Id%></h1>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406961/how-to-call-a-variable-in-code-behind-to-aspx-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do:

```
<h1><%=Id()%></h1>
```

This will display the return value of the method.

You may see: [Introduction to ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976112)

Comment: That worked! Thanks @Habib 
I had tried this without % before.

Comment: @umd3330 Please mark this as a solution that fixed your problem

Comment: Thanks @sab669 . Just did that. New to the community :)

Answer (score 1):

Injecting Code `<%= //some code here %>` into the HTML it is possible with ASP.NET. However I will recommend to use a literal control instead to always keep the separation between  the controller and the UI. Better may be:

Html:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

**Code:**

```
Literal1.Text = "My Value"
```

Comment: Thanks Dalorzo, That was a good technique.