# ASP.NET how does markup access to variables in code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin-studio

I have a webform with a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" text="Click me"
            OnClientClick="printVideos(new Object(),new EventArgs(),url,linkName)"/>
```

and the `OnClientClick` event is

```
<script language= "c#" type="text/C#" runat= "server">
    private void printVideos(Object sender, EventArgs e, string url, string linkName) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Response.Write("<a href='"+url+"'target_blank>'"+linkName+"</a>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Where `url` and `linkName` are defined in the C# code-behind as private `string`s within the class.

The button does not work, and there are warnings showing that `url` and `linkName` are not used. What should I do to let the markup access to the code-behind variables?

Comment: Your C# code should be server side, i.e. in the codebehind file, not in the markup.

Comment: `OnClientClick` is used for executing JavaScript code locally, not server side.

Comment: So it's not possible for the markup to access the data in the class, but it's possible vice Versa?

Comment: It doesn't give me errors using c# for scripting, but indeed js is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are trying to run server side code on the client - change `OnClientClick` to `OnClick`.

Next, you will need to set the protection level of your `linkName` and `url` properties so that your ASPX markup can access them. You can set this to either `public` or `protected` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406983/3037988)). Finally, remove the extra arguments from the `printVideos` method - the `OnClick` handler expects a specific method signature. So, your button markup should look something like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" text="Click me" OnClick="printVideos"/>
```

And your script...

```
<script language= "c#" type="text/C#" runat= "server">
    private void printVideos(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Response.Write("<a href='"+url+"'target_blank>'"+linkName+"</a>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

And in your codebehind for the page, declaring your variables:

```
protected string url = "...";
protected string linkName = "...";
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the `OnClick` method expects some parameters from outside of the class?

Comment: @DylanChen The default `OnClick` handlers only take the two parameters above (`Object sender, EventArgs e`). There are other ways to get external information into your handler, but you can't pass it as a standard parameter - without knowing a bit more about what it is you're trying to achieve, I can't recommend one way or another.