# C# Web application : can't access to codebehind's variable from Masterpage

Tags: c#, variables, web-applications, code-behind

I have created a new Web Application in Visual Studio. But I can not access to a variable from a Masterpage content to the codebehind of the same masterpage :

I have a .master page :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="Intra.Private.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> </head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <%=Test %>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form> </body> </html>
```

The .master.cs fil contains :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Intra.Private
{
    public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        public string Test = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The "<%=Test %>" methods doesn't works : I get the error **"Test" doesn't exist in the current context** ...

I have already tried to declare `protected string Test` instead of `public string Test` but it's not better...

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406961/how-to-call-a-variable-in-code-behind-to-aspx-page)?

Comment: Unfortunately yes... I've tried with protected and with all the suggestion in this article... it seams specific to Masterpage and Web App C#... ?