# Unable to access Variable in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use variable from back end. actually i'm trying to create copy the solution from the existing one. In the old solution it works fine but in new solution I am unable to access the code behind variable.

**Here is my code:**

```
 public static string DefaultURL { get { return Global.URL; } }
```

here is aspx page

```html
<a href="<%= DefaultURL %>">
  <img src="../Content/img/logohome.png" class="img-responsive "       
  style="width: 111px;" />
</a>
```

But the variable `DefaultURL` gives an error like "The name DefaultURL does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Try to use the full namespace ie. MyProgram.MyClass.DefaultURL

Comment: why does it have to be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this solution:

```
public string DefaultURL { get { return DefaultURL ; } }
```

**UPDATE:** It can also be declared as `protected`, as stated in the comments below.

Then, to call it on the ASPX side:

> <%=DefaultURL%>

Note that this won't work if you place it on a server tag attribute. For example:

> <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%=DefaultURL%>" />

This isn't valid. This is:

> <div><%=DefaultURL%></div>

Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406961/how-to-call-a-variable-in-code-behind-to-aspx-page) Which is more Helpfull you will find the whole example also.