# How to add C# variables to html modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, modalpopupextender

In my `ASP.Net` app, I have a button that launches a modal. The `onClick` event fires the C# behind code that launches a modal. I am then calling a data table and populating string variables with values from the data table:

```
   protected void uxTicketHistoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key", "launchModal();", true);

        DataTable ticketHist = _dtMgr.GetContactInfoByName(uxContactDropdownList.SelectedValue);
        string rName = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorName"].ToString();
        string rPhone = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorPhone"].ToString();
        string rPhoneExt = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorPhoneExt"].ToString();
        string rEmail = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorEmail"].ToString(); ;
        string rState = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorState"].ToString();
        string rOrg = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorOrg"].ToString();
    }
```

What I want to do now is add those variable values to my modal inside the panel.

```
<asp:Button ID="uxTicketHistoryButton" runat="server" Text="Show Ticket History"  style="color: blue;" OnClick="uxTicketHistoryButton_Click"/>&nbsp;

<!-- ModalPopupExtender-->
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="uxTicketHistoryModal" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="uxTicketHistoryButton"CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">                                
        **** Add variable values here ****
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

How do I add the variables from my .cs file to the modal panel in my .aspx file so that it shows up like this (values in the { } )?
[image]

**UPDATE**
This issue seems to be related to the modal interfering with the `_Click` event function of my button. I have posted an [additional question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829808/how-do-i-get-around-modal-interfering-with-button-click-event) to resolve this problem first. Then, I believe one of the solutions below may work. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Possible duplicate if I understand the issue correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406961/how-to-call-a-variable-in-code-behind-to-aspx-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webform:

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">                                
            Name: <asp:Literal ID="Name" runat="server" /><br>
            Organization: <asp:Literal ID="Organization" runat="server" /><br>
            etc....
            <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

Codebehind:

```
Name.Text = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorName"].ToString(); 
Organization.Text = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorOrg"].ToString()
```

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like it would work, but its not showing up.

Comment: What's not showing up exactly? The "variables" or the modal?

Comment: The modal launches and the text (Ex: "Name: ") shows up, but then the space next to the text is blank. I have it set up just like your example:  `<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">Name: <asp:Literal ID="Name" runat="server" /><br>...</asp:Panel>`

Comment: Is `uxTicketHistoryButton_Click` firing for sure? Does your `ticketHist` row contain data? Place a breakpoint in `uxTicketHistoryButton_Click` to see the values and if its getting hit.

Comment: Aha, that is the source of the issue. See my above edit. I have added an additional question. It appears that the modal launching interferes with the `_Click` function for the button, which grabs the data. So nothing is getting returned.

Comment: Alright, I was able to get this to work. I believe @Joey Phillips solution would work too, but this seemed like the easiest to apply to my current situation. Thanks!

Comment: His solution would work for Asp.Net MVC and Razor only. From your posted code, you are strictly in Web Forms world.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET Razor to post your c# variables directly into your html.

For Example

```
<!-- Single statement block -->
@{ var myMessage = "Hello World"; }

<!-- Inline expression or variable -->
<p>The value of myMessage is: @myMessage</p> 

<!-- Multi-statement block -->
@{
var greeting = "Welcome to our site!";
var weekDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
var greetingMessage = greeting + " Here in Huston it is: " + weekDay;
}
<p>The greeting is: @greetingMessage</p>
```

**OR**

you could use `get` and `set` methods to post your variables to the modal from you .cs .

```
  public class yourModalPage
    {
        public string RequestorName { get; set; }

    }
```

Then you can send values to your modal from your .cs with

```
yourModalPage.RequestorName = "RequestorName";
```