# How do I get around modal interfering with button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick, modal-dialog

In my ASP.Net Web Form App, I have a button, and that button is suppose to launch an `ajaxToolKit: ModalPopupExtender` modal.

```
<asp:Button ID="uxTicketHistoryButton" runat="server" Text="Show Ticket History"  style="color: blue;" OnClick="uxTicketHistoryButton_Click"/>&nbsp;
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="uxTicketHistoryModal" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="uxTicketHistoryButton"CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">
....
</asp:Panel ID>
```

I had asked a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816450/how-to-add-c-sharp-variables-to-html-modal/54816635?noredirect=1#comment96410288_54816635) on how to insert C# variable values into the modal, but it seems my problem there is that the modal seems to be interfering with my button `click event` function; essentially keeping it from firing. The function is suppose to get the data I need to plug into the modal once the button is clicked and the modal launched.

```
protected void uxTicketHistoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable ticketHist = _dtMgr.GetContactInfoByName(uxContactDropdownList.SelectedValue);
    string rName = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorName"].ToString();
    string rPhone = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorPhone"].ToString();
    ....
}
```

I have noticed several odd things while debugging: 1) I put break points on the string variables (to see what the values were being returned) while debugging. After clicking the button, it goes right over the breakpoints (I assume that means its not "firing" that code.2) I can remove all of the code from inside the `_Click` function and the modal still launches when I click the button 3) If I comment out the modal code and click the button, the `_Click` event code fires fine and I can see the values for the string variables. So, I am assuming that the way I have the modal set (I suspect its related to using `TargetControlID="uxTicketHistoryButton"`) is the problem. How do I get around my modal interfering with button click event? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your modal does popup regardless of the code in your `_Click` event right?

Comment: Yep. As I mentioned, if I delete everything between the `{ }` in `uxTicketHistoryButton_Click`, the modal still launches when I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you found one of those `ajaxToolkit` [quirks](https://forums.asp.net/t/1969191.aspx?ModalPopupExtender%20OK%20Button%20click%20event%20not%20firing%20). Try this:

Create a hidden button:

```
<asp:button id="hiddenButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
```

Change your Extender to target said button:

```
TargetControlID="hiddenButton"
```

Then in your _Click event, show the modal:

```
protected void uxTicketHistoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable ticketHist = _dtMgr.GetContactInfoByName(uxContactDropdownList.SelectedValue);
    string rName = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorName"].ToString();
    string rPhone = ticketHist.Rows[0]["RequestorPhone"].ToString();
    ....

    uxTicketHistoryModal.Show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works!! So weird that you have to point it to a "hidden" button. Now if I can just get the data to show up in the html! ;-) Going back to your solution from the previous question. Thanks again!