# Data URI is double-encoded by AntiXssEncoder

Tags: asp.net, xss, antixsslibrary

We have an ASP.Net Webforms (.Net 4.7.2) site. We've enabled the [built-in XSS protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder) by adding to `web.config`:

```
   <httpRuntime encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder" ... />
```

This works fine, apart from in one place: we have some code that generates a small image, and embeds it within the page using a Data URI:

(aspx)

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server">
```

(C#)

```
  image1.ImageUrl = dataURI;
```

and `dataURI` is normally something like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMMAAADDAQMAAAA ...
```

This works fine without the AntiXssEncoder, but with that in place the rendered HTML turns into:

```
<img id="image1" src="data%3Aimage/png%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA ...
```

... so the unsafe characters in the "header" of the src has been encoded, and the image doesn't display on the browser.

How can I disable the AntiXssEncoder for this one image object, or otherwise force the Data URI to get to the browser without being re-encoded? There is no user input on this particular page.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to "do it yourself". Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406983/11534

Bascially

1. Declare a public property in your code-behind file with the image data. Let's say "ImageData" (`public string ImageData {get;set;}`) and set it to hold the base64 data.
2. Replace `<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server">` with `<img src="<% =ImageData %>" />`